# How to activate partial mode in Z3py?

Tags: python, z3, z3py, pysmt

I am using Z3's Python bindings and am curious wether partial mode would speed up my model. However there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in Python. (`set_param(...)` doesn"t seem to have a parameter for it)

I considered migrating to [pySMT](https://pypi.org/project/pySMT/) since it claims to support partial mode for Z3, but I would prefer to keep Z3Py.

Bonus question: Would partial mode actually do me any good? I am simulating computer memory in Arrays and want Z3 to ignore entries that are never referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can set partial models:

```
from z3 import *

print get_param('model.partial')
set_param('model.partial', True)
print get_param('model.partial')
```

This prints:

```
false
true
```

Regarding your bonus question: I doubt partial models will buy you anything. SMT solvers typically find a model in case of `sat` and then complete the model as necessary. The "finding the model" part is typically the costly action, not completing the model. But it of course depends on your particular problem; so it wouldn't hurt to try.